# Postgresql extracting 'epoch' from timestamp cuts off last date in date range

Tags: postgresql

My table has the column event_ts with column type numeric.

Here is my query:

```
select 
    min(to_timestamp(event_ts)), max(to_timestamp(event_ts))
from 
    table1  
where 
    event_ts >= extract('epoch' from '2021-07-01'::timestamp) and 
    event_ts <= extract('epoch' from '2021-07-31'::timestamp)
```

However, the results are

```
min: 2021-06-30 20:00:00.000 -0400  
max: 2021-07-30 20:00:00.000 -0400
```

I would think the where clause would include data from 2021-07-01 to 2021-07-31.
There is data for July 31st, 2021.

Why does this query start at 2021-06-30 and end 2021-07-30?

Comment: with timestamp values (or the [dreaded](https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/epoch-mania/) epoch) better us `<` for the upper limit and use the next day: `< '2021-08-01'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
show timezone;
  TimeZone  
------------
 US/Pacific

 select extract('epoch' from '2021-07-01'::timestamp);
      extract      
-------------------
 1625097600.000000

select to_timestamp(1625097600);;
      to_timestamp       
-------------------------
 06/30/2021 17:00:00 PDT

select extract('epoch' from '2021-07-01'::timestamptz);
      extract      
-------------------
 1625122800.000000
(1 row)

test(5432)=# select to_timestamp(1625122800);
      to_timestamp       
-------------------------
 07/01/2021 00:00:00 PDT
```

So by using `timestamp` you are creating a local time offset by the timezone offset. Using `timestamptz` will return a timestamp at `0:00:00`.

This is because from here:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT

> epoch

> For timestamp with time zone values, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC (negative for timestamps before that); for date and timestamp values, the nominal number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00, without regard to timezone or daylight-savings rules; for interval values, the total number of seconds in the interval

`Epoch` is based on UTC timezone.

Not sure why you are using `epoch` anyway?

Why not?:

```
...
where
    event_ts  between '2021-07-01'::timestamptz and '2021-07-31'::timestamptz
```

Comment: If I don't use the epoch  EXTRACT('epoch' from '2021-07-01'::timestamptz) I get and error SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: numeric >= timestamp with time zone
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: If I do this, r.event_ts >= EXTRACT('epoch' from '2021-07-01'::timestamp) and r.event_ts <= EXTRACT('epoch' from '2021-08-01'::timestamp)  I get the right date ranges. Thank you!

Comment: Why do the `EXTRACT(`epoch` ...)` at all? It does not gain you anything and is a potential source of error. Just use the `timestamptz` values directly.

Comment: Finally dawned on me  `event_ts`  is a numeric field. So the comparison needs to be done numeric <--> numeric. Still I would think about changing that field to a `timestamptz` field at some point.